# flutter app iOS build failing with xcode 13 - Archive Failed

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods, app-store, ipa

I'm currently facing a problem with building the .ipa file for my Flutter app so that I can publish it on the App Store. Just to clarify, I can run the app on the simulator without any issues. I'm also able to build the iOS project using `flutter build ios` without any problems. However, I'm running into an error when I attempt to build the **.ipa** file using `flutter build ipa.`

Xcode's output:

```
Writing result bundle at path:
    /var/folders/xk/73bjkq2166n49x3b_5p4wb4m0000gn/T/flutter_tools.AFm5sc/flutter_ios_build_temp_dircJf2uh/temporary_xcresult_bundle

4 warnings generated.
1 warning generated.
4 warnings generated.
1 warning generated.
/Users/mehdi/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location-4.4.0/ios/Classes/LocationPlugin.m:176:13: warning: 'UIAlertView' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - UIAlertView is
deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location is Disabled"
            ^
In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/mehdi/Downloads/travel_app/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/location/location-prefix.pch:2:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAlertView.h:27:12: note: 'UIAlertView' has been
explicitly marked deprecated here
@interface UIAlertView : UIView
           ^
/Users/mehdi/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location-4.4.0/ios/Classes/LocationPlugin.m:176:48: warning: 'UIAlertView' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - UIAlertView is
deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location is Disabled"
                                               ^
In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/mehdi/Downloads/travel_app/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/location/location-prefix.pch:2:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAlertView.h:27:12: note: 'UIAlertView' has been
explicitly marked deprecated here
@interface UIAlertView : UIView
           ^
2 warnings generated.
/Users/mehdi/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-13.0.0/ios/Classes/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.m:6:17: warning: method definition for 'setRegisterPlugins:'
not found [-Wincomplete-implementation]
@implementation FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin {
                ^
In file included from /Users/mehdi/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-13.0.0/ios/Classes/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.m:1:
/Users/mehdi/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-13.0.0/ios/Classes/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.h:5:1: note: method 'setRegisterPlugins:' declared here
+ (void)setRegisterPlugins:(FlutterPluginRegistrantCallback *)callback;
^
1 warning generated.
/Users/mehdi/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.8.0/ios/Classes/InAppBrowser/InAppBrowserWebViewController.swift:565:13: warning: setter for 'statusBarStyle' was
deprecated in iOS 9.0: Use -[UIViewController preferredStatusBarStyle]
            UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle(rawValue: previousStatusBarStyle)!
            ^
/Users/mehdi/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.8.0/ios/Classes/Types/URLCredential.swift:14:25: warning: comparing non-optional value of type '[Any]' to 'nil'
always returns true
        if certificates != nil {
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~
/Users/mehdi/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.8.0/ios/Classes/Util.swift:86:25: warning: 'spotlightSuggestion' was deprecated in iOS 10.0: renamed to
'WKDataDetectorTypes.lookupSuggestion'
                return .spotlightSuggestion
                        ^
/Users/mehdi/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.8.0/ios/Classes/Util.swift:86:25: note: use 'WKDataDetectorTypes.lookupSuggestion' instead
                return .spotlightSuggestion
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                        WKDataDetectorTypes.lookupSuggestion
/Users/mehdi/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.8.0/ios/Classes/Util.swift:121:31: warning: 'spotlightSuggestion' was deprecated in iOS 10.0: renamed to
'WKDataDetectorTypes.lookupSuggestion'
            if type.contains(.spotlightSuggestion) {
                              ^
/Users/mehdi/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.8.0/ios/Classes/Util.swift:121:31: note: use 'WKDataDetectorTypes.lookupSuggestion' instead
            if type.contains(.spotlightSuggestion) {
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                              WKDataDetectorTypes.lookupSuggestion
/Users/mehdi/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.8.0/ios/Classes/Util.swift:216:21: warning: immutable value 'j' was never used; consider replacing with '_' or
removing it
                for j in ipv6.count...8 {
                    ^
                    _
/Users/mehdi/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress_common-1.0.2/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadataExif.m:9:9: warning: non-portable path to file
'"SYMetadataExif.h"'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
#import "SYMetadataEXIF.h"
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        "SYMetadataExif.h"
/Users/mehdi/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress_common-1.0.2/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadataExif.m:41:65: warning: 'kCGImagePropertyExifSubsecTimeOrginal'
is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - No longer supported [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
             SYStringSel(subsecTimeOriginal):       (NSString *)kCGImagePropertyExifSubsecTimeOrginal,
                                                                ^
In module 'ImageIO' imported from /Users/mehdi/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress_common-1.0.2/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadataExif.m:10:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Headers/CGImageProperties.h:248:34: note:
'kCGImagePropertyExifSubsecTimeOrginal' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
IMAGEIO_EXTERN const CFStringRef kCGImagePropertyExifSubsecTimeOrginal IMAGEIO_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED(10.4, 10.11, 4.0, 10.0);
                                 ^
2 warnings generated.
/Users/mehdi/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress_common-1.0.2/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadata.m:49:36: warning: 'ALAsset' is deprecated: first deprecated in
iOS 9 - Use PHAsset from the Photos framework instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
+ (instancetype)metadataWithAsset:(ALAsset *)asset
                                   ^
In module 'AssetsLibrary' imported from /Users/mehdi/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress_common-1.0.2/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadata.m:14:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/Headers/ALAsset.h:40:12: note: 'ALAsset' has been
explicitly marked deprecated here
@interface ALAsset : NSObject {
           ^
/Users/mehdi/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress_common-1.0.2/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadata.m:52:5: warning: 'ALAssetRepresentation' is deprecated: first
deprecated in iOS 9 - Use PHImageRequestOptions with the PHImageManager from the Photos framework instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
    ^
In module 'AssetsLibrary' imported from /Users/mehdi/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress_common-1.0.2/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadata.m:14:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/Headers/ALAssetRepresentation.h:20:12: note:
'ALAssetRepresentation' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
@interface ALAssetRepresentation : NSObject {
           ^
/Users/mehdi/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress_common-1.0.2/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadata.m:52:52: warning: 'defaultRepresentation' is deprecated: first
deprecated in iOS 9 - Use PHImageRequestOptions with the PHImageManager from the Photos framework instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
                                                   ^
In module 'AssetsLibrary' imported from /Users/mehdi/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress_common-1.0.2/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadata.m:14:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/Headers/ALAsset.h:49:1: note:
'defaultRepresentation' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
- (ALAssetRepresentation *)defaultRepresentation AL_DEPRECATED(4, "Use PHImageRequestOptions with the PHImageManager from the Photos framework instead");
^
/Users/mehdi/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress_common-1.0.2/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadata.m:53:57: warning: 'metadata' is deprecated: first deprecated in
iOS 9 - Use CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex() to retrieve metadata from an image returned by the PHImageManager from the Photos framework instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    return [self metadataWithDictionary:[representation metadata]];
                                                        ^
In module 'AssetsLibrary' imported from /Users/mehdi/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress_common-1.0.2/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadata.m:14:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/Headers/ALAssetRepresentation.h:56:1: note:
'metadata' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
- (NSDictionary *)metadata AL_DEPRECATED(4, "Use CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex() to retrieve metadata from an image returned by the PHImageManager from the Photos framework instead");
^
/Users/mehdi/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress_common-1.0.2/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadata.m:152:13: warning: 'ALAsset' is deprecated: first deprecated in
iOS 9 - Use PHAsset from the Photos framework instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    __block ALAsset *assetAtUrl = nil;
            ^
In module 'AssetsLibrary' imported from /Users/mehdi/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress_common-1.0.2/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadata.m:14:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/Headers/ALAsset.h:40:12: note: 'ALAsset' has been
explicitly marked deprecated here
@interface ALAsset : NSObject {
           ^
/Users/mehdi/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress_common-1.0.2/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadata.m:153:5: warning: 'ALAssetsLibrary' is deprecated: first
deprecated in iOS 9 - Use PHPhotoLibrary from the Photos framework instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    ALAssetsLibrary* library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    ^
In module 'AssetsLibrary' imported from /Users/mehdi/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress_common-1.0.2/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadata.m:14:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/Headers/ALAssetsLibrary.h:78:12: note:
'ALAssetsLibrary' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
@interface ALAssetsLibrary : NSObject {
           ^
/Users/mehdi/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress_common-1.0.2/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadata.m:153:50: warning: 'ALAssetsLibrary' is deprecated: first
deprecated in iOS 9 - Use PHPhotoLibrary from the Photos framework instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    ALAssetsLibrary* library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
                                                 ^
In module 'AssetsLibrary' imported from /Users/mehdi/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress_common-1.0.2/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadata.m:14:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/Headers/ALAssetsLibrary.h:78:12: note:
'ALAssetsLibrary' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
@interface ALAssetsLibrary : NSObject {
           ^
/Users/mehdi/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress_common-1.0.2/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadata.m:156:49: warning: 'ALAsset' is deprecated: first deprecated in
iOS 9 - Use PHAsset from the Photos framework instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    [library assetForURL:assetURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
                                                ^
In module 'AssetsLibrary' imported from /Users/mehdi/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress_common-1.0.2/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadata.m:14:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/Headers/ALAsset.h:40:12: note: 'ALAsset' has been
explicitly marked deprecated here
@interface ALAsset : NSObject {
           ^
/Users/mehdi/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress_common-1.0.2/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadata.m:156:14: warning: 'assetForURL:resultBlock:failureBlock:' is
deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9 - Use fetchAssetsWithLocalIdentifiers:options: on PHAsset to fetch assets by local identifier (or to lookup PHAssets by a previously known ALAssetPropertyAssetURL
use fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:options:) from the Photos framework instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    [library assetForURL:assetURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
             ^
In module 'AssetsLibrary' imported from /Users/mehdi/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress_common-1.0.2/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadata.m:14:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/Headers/ALAssetsLibrary.h:93:1: note:
'assetForURL:resultBlock:failureBlock:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
- (void)assetForURL:(NSURL *)assetURL resultBlock:(ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock)resultBlock failureBlock:(ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock)failureBlock AL_DEPRECATED(4, "Use
fetchAssetsWithLocalIdentifiers:options: on PHAsset to fetch assets by local identifier (or to lookup PHAssets by a previously known ALAssetPropertyAssetURL use fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:options:) from
the Photos framework instead");
^
/Users/mehdi/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress_common-1.0.2/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadata.m:167:5: warning: 'ALAssetRepresentation' is deprecated: first
deprecated in iOS 9 - Use PHImageRequestOptions with the PHImageManager from the Photos framework instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [assetAtUrl defaultRepresentation];
    ^
In module 'AssetsLibrary' imported from /Users/mehdi/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress_common-1.0.2/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadata.m:14:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/Headers/ALAssetRepresentation.h:20:12: note:
'ALAssetRepresentation' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
@interface ALAssetRepresentation : NSObject {
           ^
/Users/mehdi/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress_common-1.0.2/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadata.m:167:57: warning: 'defaultRepresentation' is deprecated: first
deprecated in iOS 9 - Use PHImageRequestOptions with the PHImageManager from the Photos framework instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [assetAtUrl defaultRepresentation];
                                                        ^
In module 'AssetsLibrary' imported from /Users/mehdi/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress_common-1.0.2/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadata.m:14:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/Headers/ALAsset.h:49:1: note:
'defaultRepresentation' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
- (ALAssetRepresentation *)defaultRepresentation AL_DEPRECATED(4, "Use PHImageRequestOptions with the PHImageManager from the Photos framework instead");
^
/Users/mehdi/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress_common-1.0.2/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadata.m:168:28: warning: 'metadata' is deprecated: first deprecated
in iOS 9 - Use CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex() to retrieve metadata from an image returned by the PHImageManager from the Photos framework instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    return [representation metadata];
                           ^
In module 'AssetsLibrary' imported from /Users/mehdi/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress_common-1.0.2/ios/Classes/SYPictureMetadata/SYMetadata.m:14:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/Headers/ALAssetRepresentation.h:56:1: note:
'metadata' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
- (NSDictionary *)metadata AL_DEPRECATED(4, "Use CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex() to retrieve metadata from an image returned by the PHImageManager from the Photos framework instead");
^
12 warnings generated.
/Users/mehdi/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress_common-1.0.2/ios/Classes/CompressFileHandler.m:109:16: warning: unused variable 'swf' [-Wunused-variable]
    const char swf[3] = {'F', 'W', 'S'};
               ^
/Users/mehdi/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image_compress_common-1.0.2/ios/Classes/CompressFileHandler.m:110:16: warning: unused variable 'swc' [-Wunused-variable]
    const char swc[3] = {'C', 'W', 'S'};
               ^
2 warnings generated.
/* com.apple.ibtool.document.warnings */
/Users/mehdi/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.8.0/ios/Storyboards/WebView.storyboard:global: warning: This file is set to build for a version older than the
deployment target. Functionality may be limited. [9]
/Users/mehdi/Downloads/travel_app/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift:18:61: warning: conditional cast from 'AppDelegate' to 'UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate' always succeeds
         UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
                                                            ^
remark: Incremental compilation has been disabled: it is not compatible with whole module optimization
/* com.apple.actool.document.warnings */
/Users/mehdi/Downloads/travel_app/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset/(null)[2d][Icon-App-50x50@1x.png]: warning: The app icon set "AppIcon" has 6 unassigned children.
/Users/mehdi/Downloads/travel_app/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset/(null)[2d][Icon-App-50x50@1x.png]: warning: The app icon set "AppIcon" has 6 unassigned children.
/* com.apple.actool.document.notices */
/Users/mehdi/Downloads/travel_app/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset/[][ipad][76x76][][][1x][][][]: notice: 76x76@1x app icons only apply to iPad apps targeting releases of iOS prior to
10.0.
/* com.apple.actool.compilation-results */
/Users/mehdi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-egpdwisazmclbuekiwxaxthpnmmr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Runner.app/AppIc
on60x60@2x.png
/Users/mehdi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-egpdwisazmclbuekiwxaxthpnmmr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Runner.app/AppIc
on76x76@2x~ipad.png
/Users/mehdi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-egpdwisazmclbuekiwxaxthpnmmr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Runner.app/Asset
s.car
/Users/mehdi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-egpdwisazmclbuekiwxaxthpnmmr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner
.build/assmehdiatalog_generated_info.plist

mkdir -p
/Users/mehdi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-egpdwisazmclbuekiwxaxthpnmmr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks
Symlinked...
readlink: illegal option -- f
usage: readlink [-n] [file ...]
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
note: Using new build system
note: Planning
note: Build preparation complete
note: Building targets in parallel
/Users/mehdi/Downloads/travel_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0
to 15.0.99. (in target 'ReachabilitySwift' from project 'Pods')
/Users/mehdi/Downloads/travel_app/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0
to 15.0.99. (in target 'OrderedSet' from project 'Pods')

Result bundle written to path:
    /var/folders/xk/73bjkq2166n49x3b_5p4wb4m0000gn/T/flutter_tools.AFm5sc/flutter_ios_build_temp_dircJf2uh/temporary_xcresult_bundle
```

Encountered error while archiving for device.

***Is there anyone who can provide a solution to this issue?